# cronjob didn't work

Tags: 18.04, cron

```
 * * * * *       root     bash /home/alan/Desktop/clientscript.sh > /home/alan/Desktop/alan.txt
```

I need output in alan.txt from the input clientscript.sh 
but it gives empty output on alan.txt 
I can't found what is the error

It is not working try some to pass this

this is with creation of live cd os ubuntu 18.04lts

Comment: How did you create that cronjob?

Comment: @PerlDuck I did not know that! awesome. I will add this info to my answer!

Comment: with the help of crontab -e

Comment: then it was the root part that broke it... see my answer and let me know if that worked for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are creating your cronjob using:

```
crontab -e
```

What ever user you are logged in as when you run the above command will be the user that the cronjob is executed as. If you want your cronjob run as root, you will need to be logged in as root or use the sudo command:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

If you create your job using the above command, that "root" part will break things. Your job should look like this:

```
  * * * * * /bin/bash /home/alan/Desktop/clientscript.sh > /home/alan/Desktop/alan.txt
```

Always use absolute paths in cronjobs otherwise they could break.

As noted by PerlDuck:

> When the above is a cronjob in some /etc/cron.d/ file, then the root
>   part is mandatory. But only there, as you correctly point out. 
>   cronjobs below /etc/cron.d are so called system cronjobs. The syntax
>   is almost the same, except you must state the user as which the job is
>   to be run in an additional column after the time specification. And of
>   course you must be root to create files in that directory – PerlDuck

So, if you are manually creating a cron file in /etc/cron.d then the original cron job will be correct:

```
  * * * * * root /bin/bash /home/alan/Desktop/clientscript.sh > /home/alan/Desktop/alan.txt
```

IMHO, creating cronjobs with `crontab -e` is much easier.

Finally, you can see any output from your cronjobs by running:

```
 grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: Yes, this was correct in my user only not on every users that which i am creating so i also tried with root like super user sudo but that also didn't work for the other users

Comment: you gave the command didn't work * * * * * root /bin/bash so and so which return empty result

Answer (score 0):

Run `crontab -e` and put following line in it:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/alan/Desktop/clientscript2.sh 1> /dev/null 2> /home/alan/test.err
```

put in your `clientscript2.sh` file following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/alan/Desktop/clientscript.sh > /home/alan/Desktop/alan.txt
```

This is running every minute. The `test.err` file will give you output error in case the command does not succeed.

Comment: This is the testing as one minute only while i am in working so that is not a problem