# Ubuntu crontab gives output to every user

Tags: 18.04, scripts, cron

[cronjob didn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074308/cronjob-didnt-work/1074353#1074353)

The above question was solved that is to bash a script and writes its output to another file so it was almost done with the same user which I have the script.

I need to **print the output to every USERS** in a machine 
And my script is user

```sh
LOGINUSER="`who'"
HOSTNAME="`hostname`"
echo "UserName: $LOGINUSER"   
echo "ComputerName: $HOSTNAME"
```

Here I have **tried to write the output on common folders that works pretty good but here I faced the issue of multiple users log in but it writes the echo `"UserName: $LOGINUSER` wrongly.

**From here I need to print the user name of logged on user and I need to print it on the desktop of every user.**

Comment: What do you mean by "print it on desktop" ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? **What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead?** Please **provide examples of both**. Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: hy Soren A here i have an script file which i need the output of the script file in an .txt file can you get me??

Comment: and well i need to get the .txt file in my user account and as well all other users also so what is the solution for it